# 2023 Integration Bee Problem 2 $\int_0^1\frac{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}{\frac{x+3}{x+4}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

So how do we solve $$\int_0^1\frac{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}{\frac{x+3}{x+4}}dx$$? This is the second problem of the [2023 integration bee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0IbNAipBdA). I changed this to $$\int_0^1\frac{x^2+5x+4}{x^2+5x+6}dx$$Then $$\int_0^1\frac{x^2+5x+4+2-2}{x^2+5x+6}dx=1-2\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+5x+6}dx$$Now by partial fractions $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{A}{x+2}dx+\int_0^1\frac{B}{x+3}dx=\ln\left(\frac{x+2}{x+3}\right)\bigg|_0^1=\ln\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)$$Substituting back into the original expression, we get the correct answer. Are there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: This is surely the simplest method

Comment: You might be able to use: $$\dfrac{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}{\frac{x+3}{x+4}}=\dfrac{1-\frac1{x+2}}{1-\frac1{x+4}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)\frac1{(x+4)^k}$$
But I don't see an easy way to go from there.

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ then integrand is $f(x+1)/f(x+3),$ but the integrand can also be written as $f(x/2+1/2)/f(x/2+1).$

Comment: Just for fun:$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(x+1\right)\left(x+4\right)}{\left(x+2\right)\left(x+3\right)}dx &\xrightarrow{x+2 \rightarrow u-\frac{1}{2}} \int_{5/2}^{7/2}\frac{u^{2}-9/4}{u^{2}-1/4}du \\ &= 1-2\int_{5/2}^{7/2}\frac{1}{u^{2}-1/4}du \\ &= 1-2\cdot\ln\left(\frac{x-1/2}{x+1/2}\right) \Biggr|_{5/2}^{7/2} \\ &=1-2\ln\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Abi But this is an answer, please post it. Maybe just copy paste.